# tcp/ip sockets on gprs modem

Tags: sockets, gprs

i want to establish a TCP/IP socket connection between a device connected to gprs modem and another device that is also connected to gprs modem.both devices are connected to gprs via sims.now for tcp/ip socket connection how a client can get destination  ip address of server in order to establish connection with it that is listening to the incoming connections.i have numbers of both devices since sims are integrated with them that allows us to access the gprs .but for tcp/ip socket we must know the destination ip address.so how can i get the ip address of other clients /servers on the network via their simnumbers to whom we wish to connect .i m using socket programming to establish tcp/ip connection

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can try one of free dynamic DNS services like [dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com) - you'd need one end to register it's IP every time it changes with a small program like [ddclient](http://ddclient.sourceforge.net/) - and then use the host name instead of numeric IP for looking up the server.

One caveat though - the devices could actually be within carrier private networks and be given non-routable [RFC1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) addresses. In that case you can only connect out.

Comment: thanks alot for ur reply...tell me how can i use DNS services...as ip address is being assigned to modem of wavecom who has its own cpu ,n OS....IDE is OPEN AT and API is M2M...the pc on which M2M is installed or is providing me the interface to work with wavecom is just a dummy entity and i hv nothing to do with pc's ip address...so plz tell me how can i use dns services as it would be done through a website 2nd how can i use ddclient pogram...i thnk it runs only in unix/linux..can i run it on M2M dat load programs on wavecom and runs them with wavecom's OS...thanking u in advance....

Answer (score 0):

What I did is, each unit constantly monitors its assigned IP address.

I use the LEON200 GPRS modem from Ublox with TCP/IP, HTTP and FTP stack. Once this IP changes, it creates a HTTP connection to my server, and use the `&_POST`, the IMEI and new IP address into a php script that updates a lookup table. Whenever any unit needs to connect to another unit, all I need to know is the IMEI number of the unit and then use the same HTTP connection to `&_POST` a request to a php script that will return the listed IP address.

This way I can connect from device to device. On my carrier, I had to activate an unrestricted APN for the GSM asigned IP addresss is not visable from the internet APN side.

I hope this will help.